# How do I remove separation between rows in a HTML table?

Tags: html, image, html-table, margin, padding

I have a html table with 3 rows and 1 column. In the top and button row I have images and in the middle row I have div.

Between my rows I see a separation (I see background of my page). I tried to set all padding and margins to zero (for tables, div and images) and I still have this separation. Can anybody, please, help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `cellspacing=0` in the `<table>` tag as well as `cellpadding=0`.

Comment: You're thinking too HTML 4 / CSS 1 / 1996.

Comment: He's using tables for formatting his page. That's HTML4/CSS1/1996. Thus, my answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work either. As for formatting with tables... He'll pick up the proper use of DIVs, so let's cut him some slack. :)

Answer (score 17):

Try using 'border-collapse':

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Did anyone get this to work? I tried and it didn't do a thing for me.

Answer (score 5):

Use this in img tag :

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Hurray! Fixed my problem!

Answer (score 4):

Gonzohunter nailed this, alright, but you may find it easier to just set the style on the table, assuming you are in a recent HTML version.

I used

```
<table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    ... 
</table>
```

This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's your H2 that's causing it. To fix it, set the top margin of it to zero:

```
<h2 style="margin-top: 0;"><span class="text">Welcome to the Colored Trails Game Page!</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to eliminate spacing from the table cells themselves.

In CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Or in [HTML 4.01/XHTML 1.0 DTD (Strict or Transitional)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  [...]
</table>
```